# Abstract inner classes used as method parameter fails to compile

Tags: java

I have the following abstract class with an abstract inner class and a getter/setter that utilizes the inner class

```
public abstract class AbstractOuterClass
{

    public abstract AbstractInnerClass getInner();  
    public abstract void setInner(AbstractInnerClass values);

    public abstract class AbstractInnerClass
    {

    }

}
```

When I try to override the setter (the getter works fine), the compiler doesn't recognize the setter as being overidden due to its method parameter being the extended abstract inner class.

```
public class OuterClassImpl extends AbstractOuterClass
{

    @Override
    public InnerClassImpl getInner() 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public  void setInner(InnerClassImpl values) 
    {
        // do stuff     
    }


    public class InnerClassImpl extends AbstractInnerClass
    {
        // define attrs
    }

}
```

I'm not sure why this is or how to get around it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the same method signature:

```
public void setInner(AbstractInnerClass values)
```

not:

```
public void setInner(InnerClassImpl values)
```

You cannot get around this, because implementing Foo means your class must behave like a Foo - which in this case means your subclass must be able to handle any `AbstractInnerClass` given to it, not just the specific `InnerClassImpl`.